# How to select only the one highest value for different ID

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, sql-limit

I have this query:

```
select  room_id, sum(cost)
from maintenance
group by room_id
```

which gives me this result:

```
 ROOM_ID  SUM(COST)
   418       2080
   211        300
   220        500
   416       1800
   505        380
   301       5500
   110       4080
   114       2400
   202        300
   511       1200
   520       1780
   208       4860
   320        600
   411        900
```

but how do I get only the highest cost from this table? meaning I want this output

```
       ROOM_ID  SUM(COST)
       301       5500
```

I've tried ways like MAX(SUM(COST)) but it just keeps giving me an error

Answer (score 3):

Just order by and limit:

```
select  room_id, sum(cost) as total_cost
from maintenance
group by room_id
order by total_cost desc 
fetch first row with ties
```

`with ties` allows top ties, if any.

In Oracle < 12.1, where the `fetch` clause is not available, an alternative uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select  room_id, sum(cost) as total_cost, 
        rank() over(order by sum(cost) desc) rn
    from maintenance
    group by room_id
) t
where rn = 1
```